# Aurelia Routing: Unable to load page when I enter the url with route

Tags: routes, aurelia

I am new to Aurelia framework and working with the contact manager tutorial on their website.

When I load the page starting from the default url: "http://localhost:9002" then proceed to "http://localhost:9002/contacts/2" it works fine. But when I attempt to load the page with just the url "http://localhost:9002/contacts/2" it fails to load, then checking the console (F12) i can see it is failing to load several .css and .js bundles. See image below. What can I do?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Why the error occurs

This error occurs because for your browser searches for the .css and .js files at "http://localhost:9002/contacts/" instead of "http://localhost:9002/" where your SPA serves these files from.

When using an SPA, you should explicitly set the base url of your page (typically) to the SPA root by adding `<base href="/">` within your `<head>` element, otherwise your browser simply searches for resources relative to the current url.

### What to do

If you are using the latest `aurelia-cli` (v2.0.2 at the time of this answer) with Webpack, your `index.ejs` file should have the following line;

```
<base href="<%- htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.baseUrl %>">
```

which pulls its value from a constant in your `webpack.config.js` file.

In `webpack.config.js` update the line

```
const baseUrl = '';
```

to

```
const baseUrl = '/';
```

Your resources should load properly afterwards.

#### Further reading

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base